# Does mvn clean install runs the surefire test before updating .m2 repository

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

How does mvn clean install works
mvn install should execute all the phases before install phase, that means it will first run the surefire test and then later update m2 respository with the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how it works.

The phases are executed in order and the installation into the local repository is the last one.

Comment: But if m2 repository is not updated. for ex: i have jar files into .m2 repo which needs to be downloaded before running the tests

Comment: Dependencies are resolved before the tests. You asked for uploads: They happen after the tests.

Answer (score 0):

With external dependencies it's simple: before compiling anything Maven downloads them.

With inter-module dependencies it's more complicated. It's important to understand that Maven first runs all phases for the 1st module, then runs all phases for the 2nd module, and so on. So depending on which phase you call there either will be a JAR file or there won't be.

Maven will try to give you as "high-quality" dependency as possible, meaning:

- if you run `mvn install` - this will put 1st module's jar into `~/.m2`, then by the time 2nd module starts - it already has a JAR dependency waiting in the local repo.
- if you run `mvn package` the JAR doesn't go to local repo, it stays in `target/`. Thus this `target/xxx.jar` will be used as a dependency.
- if you run `mvn test` there won't even be a JAR. There will only be `target/classes`. So 2nd module's compilation & runtime will have directory with classes & resources in its classpath (no JAR).

PS: this may actually lead to real implications. When you run tests in `module2` you may be reading resources of `module1` and working with their *file paths*. And everything will work fine in case of `mvn test`. But once you start running at least `mvn package` there won't be files anymore - all resources of `module2` will be in JAR and thus can be accessed only with `getResourceAsStream()`.